# How can i draw an image from the text value i get from firestore database in react?

Tags: reactjs

Normal i am drawing images like this in my react code:

```
import Gold from "../img/goldnew.png";
img_gold = new Image();
img_gold.src = Gold;
img_gold.onload = function() {
     ctx_buildings.drawImage(img_gold, 90, 0, 90, 120);
};
```

But now i will draw different images in react and choose what to draw according to a text value i get from firestore database like

```
ctx.drawImage(material, x*90, y*120, 90, 120);
```

i get "material" value from firestore and it has text value "img_gold" in it. however when i try to run react it gives me

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first snippet, the variable `img_gold` is an instance of `Image`. In your second, the variable `material` is the string `"img_gold"`, which is very different from the variable `img_gold`. It's the difference between

```
ctx_buildings.drawImage(img_gold, 90, 0, 90, 120);
```

and

```
ctx_buildings.drawImage("img_gold", 90, 0, 90, 120);
```

Try the second and see the same error.

What you need to do is set a variable equal to an `Image` instance depending on the value you get back from Firestore.

```
import Gold from "../img/goldnew.png";
import Silver from "../img/silvernew.png";

...

function getImage(material) {
  img = new Image();
  if (material === 'img_gold') {
    img.src = Gold;
  } else if (material === 'img_silver') {
    img.src = Silver;
  } else {
    // throw error or use default value
  }
}
```

Probably a better solution still would be to construct the `src` value from the string and set it without the import, but I'd need to see where `ctx` is getting defined and used to say more.